# Remove all attributes not working properly in ie8 because of extra (system default) attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, internet-explorer-8

I have a function which removes all attributes in all tags except a few like **colspan,color or align**

When I send HTML code to this function it work well in Firefox and IE9, but in IE8 and IE7 it's finding lots of attributes which the elements don't have. For example, when I send:

```
jRemoveAtt("<button color=\"red\" id=\"start\">Hello World</button>")
```

It should find the **color** attribute and skip it, then find the **id** attribute and remove it.

But in IE8 it finds more attributes like **onwrite, onunwrite, onpage, onbeforeactivate**, and more.

This function is for clean up HTML and sending it to a printable newwindow. It's cleaning up really fast but in IE8 it takes 8-9 seconds and meanwhile makes the browser unresponsive.

I don't know how I can make it to ignore unwritten attributes in HTML strings. Any ideas?

Here is my function:

```
function jRemoveAtt(x){
    if(!x)return '';
    var str=$('<div>'+x+'</div>');
    $('*',str).each(function(){
        var c=$(this);
        var attributes = $.map(this.attributes, function(item) {
            var a=item.name.toLowerCase();
            /*alert(a); */  //this alert shows the extra tags when activated
            if (a!='align'&&a!='colspan'&&a!='span'&&a!='color'&&a!='size') {
                c.removeAttr(item);
            }

        });

    });
    return $(str).html();
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in pure JS.

HTML:

```
<div color="red" id="start" align="center">Hello World</div>
```

JS:

```
var test = document.getElementById("start");
purgeAttributes(test);
postAttributes(test);

function purgeAttributes(el)
{
    //keep these attributes
    var whitelist = ["colspan", "color", "align"];
    for(var i=0;i<el.attributes.length;i++)
    {
        var attr = el.attributes.item(i);
        var whiteListCheck = false;
        //loop through whitelist
        for(var j=0;j<whitelist.length;j++)
        {
            if(attr.nodeName === whitelist[j])
            {
                whiteListCheck = true;
                break;
            }   
        }
        if(!whiteListCheck)
        {
            //second parameter means a case-sensitive search
            el.removeAttribute(attr.nodeName, 1);   
        }
    }  
}

function postAttributes(el)
{
    var txtHolder = document.createElement("p");
    var titleTxt = document.createTextNode("attributes: ");
    document.body.appendChild(txtHolder);
    txtHolder.appendChild(titleTxt);
    for(var i=0;i<el.attributes.length;i++)
    {
        var attr = el.attributes.item(i);
        if(attr.nodeValue)
        {
            var txt = document.createTextNode(attr.nodeName + ": " + attr.nodeValue + " ");
            txtHolder.appendChild(txt);
        }
    }  
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mkmcdonald/ZsezN/3/

Tested as working in Firefox 4, IE 8, IE 7 (Quirks Mode), IE 6, Chrome 4, Safari 4, and Opera 11. One small quirk to note is IE in Quirks Mode will display the `contentEditable` attribute.

Comment: there were no error on my code in a few days. i dunno why its now making me problem in ie8. i really void to change my function with another one, i was hardly made it work properly. but in this case i think i have no luck to find any better/quick solution. ill work on your suggestion.. hope it wont make another problems, and fixes. i let you know. thanks for spending time

Comment: You're accessing the attributes with `el.attributes.item(i);`. Say you remove attribute when `i=0`. Now that you're removed it, doesn't the item array reset its keys? Thus, the item that was in `item(1)` is now in `item(0)`, and since you're incrementing `i`, that second attribute will not be checked. Tested in FF, Chrome, not sure how it would react in IE or Safari.

Answer (score 0):

How about this: You're removing all of the element's attributes, correct? How about instead of removing all of it's attributes, you do this:

HTML:

```
<div id="myElement" fakeAttr="1" fakeAttr2="2">This is a test.</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var before = $("#myElement");
var after = $("<"+before[0].tagName+"/>", { html: before.html() });

alert( "Before: "+before[0].outerHTML );
alert( "After: "+after[0].outerHTML );
```

Same thing, but done in another way...

EDIT:

Added in feature where array of "good" attributes could be set...

```
var attrObj = function(el, good){
    var obj = {}, attribs = el[0].attributes;
    var tLC = function(s){ return s.toLowerCase() };

    for(var i=0; i<attribs.length; i++){
        var isGd = false;
        for(var i2=0; i2<good.length; i2++){
            if(tLC(attribs[i].name) == tLC(good[i2])){ isGd = true; break; }
        }
        if(isGd){ obj[attribs[i].name] = attribs[i].value; }
    }

    return obj;
};

var before = $("#myElement");
var newAttr = attrObj(before, ["id"]);
newAttr.html = before.html();

var after = $("<"+before[0].tagName+"/>", newAttr);

alert( "Before: "+before[0].outerHTML );
alert( "After: "+after[0].outerHTML );
```

Comment: well actually i need some of attributes. im editing entire page html code with this function, so i really need some tags like **colspan**

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment, something like this should do the trick for purging:

```
function purgeAttributes(el) {
    var curIndex = 0;
    var whitelist = ["colspan", "color", "align"];
    var initialLength = el.attributes.length;
    var whiteListCheck = false; 

    for (var i = 0; i < initialLength; i++) {
        var attr = el.attributes.item(curIndex);
        for(var j = 0; j < whitelist.length; j++) {
            if(attr.nodeName === whitelist[j]) {
                whiteListCheck = true;
                // We know that there is an item at curIndex we want to keep, proceed to the next
                curIndex++;
                break;
            }   
        }
        if(!whiteListCheck) {
            el.removeAttribute(attr.nodeName);
        }
    };
}
```